# C++ check if Palindrome

Tags: c++, strings, palindrome

Just did this simple application to check whether a string is a palindrome or not

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
  string str;
  cout << "Enter a string: "; getline(cin, str);
  cout << "Your string is: "; cout << str << endl;
  cout << "The reverse of the string is: ";
  int counter = 0;
  for (int reverseIdx = str.size() - 1, forwardIdx = 0; reverseIdx >= 0 && 
  forwardIdx < str.size(); reverseIdx--, forwardIdx++)
  {
    cout << str[reverseIdx];
    if (str[reverseIdx] == str[forwardIdx])
    {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
  if (counter == str.size())
  {
    cout << "The string is a Palindrome!" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "The string is not a Palindrome." << endl;
  }
}
```

I'm getting a string from the user, then printing out the same string (I know it's not needed in such small programs). Then using a for loop to check if every character when reversed is equal to the same character when read normally.

Then using a counter variable I am checking if it's equal to the string size, if it's then it's palindrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Advice 1: getting the job done the C++ way**

You can check whether the input string is a palindrome in one line:

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string& text) {
    return std::equal(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), text.rbegin());
}
```

**For [Incomputable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/93301/incomputable) has spoken:** You can make the above run in the worst case faster by the factor of two:

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string& text) {
    return std::equal(text.cbegin(),
                      std::prev(text.cend(), text.length() / 2),
                      text.rbegin());
}
```

**For [Deduplicator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42409/deduplicator) has spoken**: In `is_palindrome`, change `std::string&` to `std::string const&`; this will guarantee that the input string is not modified.

**Advice 2**

Whatever you implementation of the palindrome checker is, have a dedicated method that does not output the result to `std::cout`, but rather returns a boolean indicating whether the input string is a palindrome or not.

**Advice 3**

`void main()` does not compile on modern Xcode; change to `int main()`.

**Advice 4**

Please avoid

```
using namespace std;
```

since it pollutes your namespace by importing quite a lot of identifiers/type names.

**Advice 5**

```
cout << "Your string is: "; cout << str << endl;
```

You can write:

```
cout << "Your string is: " << str << endl;
```

**Alternative implementation**

I had this in mind:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrome(std::string& text) {
    return std::equal(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), text.rbegin());
}

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::getline;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << "Your string is: " << str << "\n";
    cout << "Palindrome: " << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome(str) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Those are actually solid recommendations! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SaadAl-Sabbagh You are most welcome!

Comment: @coderodde, you could also reduce amount of comparisons in the worst case by 2, changing `text.cend()` to `std::prev(text.cend(), text.size() / 2)`. Happy to see you back on C++ tag, btw.

Comment: @Incomputable Thanks! I have mentioned the suggestion of the C++ Master such as yourself in the first advice. :-)

Comment: @coderodde, thanks for the compliment :) I'm not really a master, yet

Comment: Well, your function should either accept a `std::string_view` or at least a `const std::string&`; it doesn't modify the passed argument at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Of course I have to miss this one, thanks!

Comment: @Deduplicator Would adding `nothrow` be any beneficial?

Comment: Sure, `noexcept` is nice.